# Java Mouselistener not being added

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I've creating a new game class that is basically a GUI for my game. I'm wanting to add a mouselistener so that I can check when the user is clicking on different things. However, I'm struggling to get the basics working. Here is what I have so far. The game class is significantly more complex but works fine, only the mouselistener does not. The game itself is basically a big square with lots of different shapes.

```
public class Game extends JPanel {
public Game() {

f = new JFrame();

f.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY());

        }

    });
```

alternatively I've tried just adding the mouselistener to the Game class but that didn't work either.

Comment: Where do you add your `JFrame f` onto the GUI? If you don't add it then the mouse listener won't react to anything as the frame isn't shown.

Comment: @AndyBrown how do I do that? when I try .add(f) I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself"

Comment: Do you have an application yet that shows itself on the screen?

Comment: @AndyBrown yes. It uses the paintComponent(Graphics g)override to to draw the shapes etc if that helps

Comment: Well it's hard to tell with so little code, but see if that answer makes sense to you. I know you said you added the listener to the `Game` class, but there is no reason that wouldn't work.

Comment: Listeners only work if the component it's added to has focus. Try calling `requestFocus` from the component you want the listener to work for *after* adding your components and setting the frame to visible

Comment: @VinceEmigh I did requestFocus() now but it did not work. Any ideas how I can constantly give it focus?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @VinceEmigh That's only true for `KeyListener`.  If the window has focus, and you click on a component which has a `MouseListener` registered with AND it has nothing that could potentially block the mouse event, it should trigger the listener just fine. Right now, the question reeks of a bunch of issues which are been demonstrated from the snippet of code provided by the OP

Comment: @MadProgrammer So focus doesn't have affect for mouse events? What if there were multiple listeners? I'm not on a computer, so I can't test it myself, but that seems as if it would be a problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer the only other part of this class is an overridden paintcomponent method. There are no other parts. Creating a runnable exampleis very hard because the shapes are dependent on other classes.

Comment: @VinceEmigh thanks a lot for your help so far! The result of that method is null

Comment: @VinceEmigh Actually, no it doesn't.  `JPanel` is not focusable by default ;)

Comment: @John I've made runnable example that works just fine.  Perhaps you'd like to provide one which doesn't

Comment: As you've heard (and I've learned), focus doesn't have affect on mouse events. It seems as if you should definitely be adding the listener to your game (the `JPanel`), since you are interacting with that and not the content pane (you could set it to the content pane if you wanted). As for the actual problem, I'm going to have to see more code. Please do as MadProgrammer advised and create a small runnable example of your program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

The example below does thing more the add a `MouseListener` to a `JPanel`, track the point at which the `MouseEvent` occurs and repaints the component accordingly.

[image: Click]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Point clickPoint;

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    clickPoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (clickPoint != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.fillOval(clickPoint.x - 5, clickPoint.y - 5, 10, 10);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now perhaps you'd like to provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your particualr problem.